# WPF C# Windows throws "Application has stopped working" upon Application.Current.Shutdown(); call

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, visual-studio-2015

I'm in process of learning C# and WPF specifically. I have a program currently written but it's having an issue closing. When a user closes the main window, the program ends, but the process continues running in the background. Each time a new window is open, a new process is created and never ends. I attempted to fix this by adding the following code to my MainWindow.xaml.cs file:

```
private void InventoryUpdater_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
```

This closes the process but causes a window to pop up that acts like the program shutdown incorrectly and prompting the user to "Close the program". That window states, "[Application Name] has stopped working.

How can I end my application process without it prompting the user each time they want to close? Is it possible I've not properly disposed something?

Comment: `Environment.Exit(0)` instead ?

Comment: `Environment.Exit(0);` doesn't end the process. When I try that, it just closes the application window but the processes continue to run and stack up.

Comment: That is not true. The docs states : *Exit terminates an application immediately, even if other threads are running* : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exit(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm just going off of what is happening for me. When I execute `Environment.Exit(0);` inside of my `InventoryUpdater_Closed` method, the process still shows in my Task Manager. I have to end it manually for it to close.

Comment: Why don't you actually fix the *real* problem (your app blocking the process from exiting) instead of hacking in a process kill?

Comment: I agree with @SledgeHammer that you need to go after the root cause. Make sure any background threads, tasks, etc, get killed when your application is exiting, and make sure that you're disposing your IDisposables properly. Something is keeping your application open, and that's usually a sign that something isn't working quite right.

Comment: I wasn't sure what was the real problem. Like I said, I'm new so I was hoping interaction through here would confirm what the real problem is. I would prefer doing it the right way and not "hacking in a process kill". I do have background threads that run at a certain point but I'm closing the program before the threads are started (requires button click to start the threads).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out what was causing the prompt and what was causing the unending process.

The prompt had to do with my opening and closing of the other 3 windows. Here is what I changed to stop getting the error from `Application.Current.Shutdown()`. I changed this code:

```
private void settingsWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        updateSettings();
        e.Cancel = true;
        main.Show();
        Hide();
    }

private void settingsButton_MouseUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        settingsWindow settingsWindow = new settingsWindow(this);
        if (!settingsWindow.settingsOpen)
        {
            settingsWindow.Show();
            Hide();
        }
    }
```

To this code:

```
private void settingsWindow_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        updateSettings();
    }

private void settingsButton_MouseUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        settingsWindow settingsWindow = new settingsWindow(this);
        if (!settingsWindow.settingsOpen)
        {

            settingsWindow.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

Once I close `main` it was going back through the other window instances that I had initialized on load and was cycling through their Closing events. Once it was getting to `main.Show()`, it was failing to Show something that had already been closed.

Once I did that, I was about to figure out that the original initializing of the additional windows in my `Loaded` event was causing the additional trace backs that weren't ending. Here is what I changed. I changed this:

```
private void InventoryUpdater_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        settingsWindow settings = new settingsWindow(this);
        sftpSettings severSettings = new sftpSettings(settings);
        TimeSpan na = queueCustomTask();
        Stop = true;
        runManually.IsEnabled = true;
        ssdRunManually.IsEnabled = true;
        startAutoRun.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

To this:

```
private void InventoryUpdater_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan na = queueCustomTask();
        Stop = true;
        runManually.IsEnabled = true;
        ssdRunManually.IsEnabled = true;
        startAutoRun.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

I'm not even sure why the initializing was still there. Everything had been switched to static global variables so removing those two lines affected nothing. Thanks for all the shoves in the right direction!